# Calling Windows COM interface and get Response

Tags: java, windows, com, native, jacob

I have a system that has Windows COM interface so that external applications can connect to it and it has following details

Interface: InterfaceName
Flags: (1234) Dual OleAutomation Dispatchable
GUID: {ABCDEFG-ABCD-1234-ABCD-ABCDE1234} 
I'd like to connect to this interface through Java Spring Application, it will sends a request to this interface and process the response.

I've tried to use the following code

```
 ActiveXComponent mf = new ActiveXComponent("ApplicationName.InterfaceName");
        try {
          Dispatch f2 = mf.QueryInterface(" {ABCDEFG-ABCD-1234-ABCD-ABCDE1234} ");
          Dispatch.put(f2,  201,  new Variant("Request String"));
        } catch (Exception e) {
          e.printStackTrace();
        }
```

The executable file opens but it doesn't do what I want. I want to do the following.

1. How do I make sure, my interface has bee registered, I can see it
   under

   ```
   Computer\HKEY_CLASSES_ROOT\ApplicationName.InterfaceName
   ```
2. Using `ActiveXComponent` opens the instance of application, which is not required. Application is already running.
3. call the interface with dispid.
4. Retreive the response from the call/put/invoke ( which suits best
   for my requiremet ? ) and process the response.

I'm working first time with JAVA-COM_Interface and don't have much experience with it also I could find very few examples on the internet for it and I tried to convert the example I found for my project, also I am not sure the approach I am taking to call the interface is correct or not I would be glad if you can give a hand!

Answer (score 0):

I have resolved this using JACOB lib.

1) Download JACOB folder from [here](https://sourceforge.net/projects/jacob-project/).

2) Check your application is working & has details under

```
Computer\HKEY_CLASSES_ROOT\ApplicationName.InterfaceName
```

3) Make sure **ApplicationName.dll** file is registered. If not use this link for more info
[regsvr32](https://ss64.com/nt/regsvr32.html)

4) Use this Java Code to send data to COM Interface with below simple code.

```
Dispatch dispatch = new Dispatch("Application.InterfaceName");            
Variant response = Dispatch.call(dispatch, <DISPID>, message); 
syso(response.getString()); // to print the response
```

Hope this helps.